# Delete Site Collection from Recycling Bin

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom, recycle-bin

How does one delete a site collection from the Recycling bin using C# CSOM? I can do it with the Cmdlet in Powershell like so:

```
Connect-SPOService https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com
Remove-SPODeletedSite -Identity https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/deletedSite
```

But I want to do it in a Console application, any ideas?

Comment: check this one if it helps https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-Online-Delete-a-e0aabe36

Comment: that script is just to delete it the first time. I need to delete it from the tenant recycle bin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Tenant object allows you to delete the site from the recycling bin as well as deleting the site in the first place. This code example is an extension of the [RemoveSite](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.online.sharepoint.tenantadministration.tenant.removesite.aspx) example to include removing the site from the recycling bin.

```
/// <summary>
/// Remove a site permanently
/// </summary>
/// <param name="adminUrl">The tenant admin URL</param>
/// <param name="targetUrl">site url</param>
internal void RemoveSite(string adminUrl, String targetUrl)
{
    // Connect to the site and tenant
    var ctx = new ClientContext(adminUrl);
    var tenant = new Tenant(ctx);
    // Delete the site and send it to the recycling bin
    var spoOperation = tenant.RemoveSite(targetUrl);
    ctx.Load(spoOperation);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    Console.WriteLine("Time: " + DateTime.Now);
    WaitForOperation(spoOperation, "Deleting site")

    Console.WriteLine("Time: " + DateTime.Now);

    // Delete the site from the recycling bin
    spoOperation = tenant.RemoveDeletedSite(targetUrl);
    WaitForOperation(spoOperation, "Removing deleted site");
    Console.WriteLine("Time: " + DateTime.Now);
}

/// <summary>
/// Wait of an SpoOperation to complete
/// </summary>
private void WaitForOperation(SpoOperation operation, string operationName)
{
    while (!operation.IsComplete)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        ctx.Load(operation);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        Console.WriteLine($"{operationName} status: {(operation.IsComplete ? "waiting" : "complete")}");
    }
}
```

[Tenant.RemoveDeletedSite](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.online.sharepoint.tenantadministration.tenant.removedeletedsite.aspx)

[Tenant.RemoveDeletedSitePreferId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.online.sharepoint.tenantadministration.tenant.removedeletedsitepreferid.aspx)

Comment: I'm getting an error on the first ExecuteQuery() Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: 'Current site is not a tenant administration site.'

Comment: Also getting the error on ClientRuntimeContext - inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: Updated the example, pass in the -admin.sharepoint.com site to the context instead of the site targeted for deletion.

Comment: Getting 403 on the first ExecuteQuery() - maybe I need global tenant admin rights?
Getting this error on RemoveDeletedSite: The property or field 'IsComplete' has not been initialized.